# How to do I loop over list of artists to get LastFM artist tags?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, last.fm

I have a list of musicians/artists in an excel document.  I need to figure out what genre they are considered.  LastFm has tags that basically give some idea of what genre different artists/groups are.

LastFM has an api that you can call to get this.  It is the `artist.getTags` method. Lastfm doesn't want you to call your api more than 5 times per second per ip.

I can put my excel column in an array or object.  What's the best way to call the lastfm api 5 times per second to loop over my list?